# Принцип фрагментов

Tags: java, android

Есть FragmentManager, он управляет двумя структурами: такими как стек транзакций и список фрагментов.

И я пытаюсь понять, что это за структуры такие?

Вот пример кода

```
Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);


if(fragment == null){

    fragment = new CrimeFragment();
    fm.beginTransaction() // Создать новую транзакцию фрагментов
      .add(R.id.fragmentContainer,fragment) // добавляем фрагмент в списрк
      .commit();  //  закрепляем
}
```

В итоге данный код делает следующее:

Получение существующего фрагмента по идентификатору контейнерного представления.(СНачала мы запрпашиваем у FragmentManager фрагмент с идентификатором котейнерного представленя. Если этот фрагмент уже находится в списке, FragmentManager возвращает его. //Какой этот фрамгент??

Вопрос: а если этих фрагментов несколько? Как он возвратит несколько?

Так вот, если fragment == null, то мы создаем фрагмент,создаем новую транзакцию, и добавляем фрагмент в список фрагментов,далее закрпепляем.

А что тогда такое Стек транзакций?

Comment: Книгу "Android. Программирование для профессионалов" читаете? Там же вроде все доступно объяснено. Вы обращаетесь к фрагменту по id его контейнера. Можно заменить содержимое контейнера другим фрагментом. Если у вас несколько фрагментов одновременно в активити, то у каждого из них должен быть свой контейнер со своим id. Стек транзакций используется для быстрого переключения между разными фрагментами

Comment: @Fitz, про стек транзакций хотел бы услышать поподробнее

Comment: @Fitz, у меня 3 фрагмента, сначала я отобразил 1 фрагмент, потом 2 фрагмент (далее активность сломалась), происходит onCreate активности и восстановление фрагмента, но я так понимаю восстановиться только фрагмент который был отображен последним? 2 фрагмент не восстановиться с его данными?

Comment: Ну, например, заменяете один фрагмент другим в активити и добавляете его в стек командой addToBackStack("name"). Если после этого нажать Back, то сперва будет возвращен предыдущий фрагмент, вместо выхода из активити. Если стек транзакций пуст, то после нажатия Back активити закроется

Comment: что значит "активность сломалась"? если нужно, чтобы фрагмент, допустим, поворот экрана переживал, то можно включить ему setRetainInstance(true)

Comment: @Fitz, ну допустим пересоздание активности при повороте экрана.
ФРагмент восстановиться только последний?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44642/discussion-between-fitz-and-martinez-toni).

Answer (score 1):

> Какой этот фрамгент??

С помощью метода `findFragmentById(int id)` Вы запрашиваете фрагмент с определенным идентификатором контейнерного представления (`int id`), вот именно этот фрагмент Вы и получаете.

В строке `.add(R.id.fragmentContainer,fragment)` этот самый идентификатор – `R.id.fragmentContainer`.

> Вопрос: а если этих фрагментов несколько? Как он возвратит несколько?

Их не может быть несколько. В любой момент времени одному идентификатору контейнерного представления может:

1. Не соответствовать ни один фрагмент, тогда `findFragmentById(int id)` возвратит `null`.
2. Соответствовать один фрагмент.

Стек транзакций – это, условно говоря, некоторый список, который хранит (если Вы ему скажете) действия, который Вы совершаете с Вашими фрагментами.

Comment: А что такое список фрагментов? Где он?Я понять что-то не могу.

Вот есть фрагментМенеджер)
А где список фрагментов??


у меня 3 фрагмента, сначала я отобразил 1 фрагмент, потом 2 фрагмент (далее активность сломалась), происходит onCreate активности и восстановление фрагмента, но я так понимаю восстановиться только фрагмент который был отображен последним? 2 фрагмент не восстановиться с его данными(если я захочу его отобразить?)

Comment: @MartinezToni, Список фрагментов Вы можете получить с помощью метода `getFragments()` `FragmentManager`'а. По остальным вопросам мысли есть, но лучше подождать более компетентных товарищей.

Comment: Как добавить фармгмент в список фрагментов?

Comment: @MartinezToni `fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment).commit();`

Comment: Т.е я создаю транзакцию, которая добавляет фрагмент в список фрагментов правильно?)
И заменяю я фрагменты из списка фрагментов верно?

Comment: @MartinezToni, На оба вопроса – да.